# Python does not create another object when a function is called twice

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I create an object inside a function in Python. When the function ends, all references to the object should be deleted (only one instance), as well as the object itself.

So in the example.

**~/my_soft/my_program.py**

```
from my_soft.my_module import deployers as D

def main():
    while True:
        ## ask and wait for user option
        if opt == 'something':
            D.my_function()
```

**~/my_soft/my_module/deployers.py**

```
from  my_soft.my_module import Deployer

def my_function():

    dep = Deployer(param1, param2)
    dep.do_something()

    return
```

**~/my_soft/my_module/__init__.py**

```
class Deployer(object):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        ## initialise my attributes

    def do_something(self):
        # method code
```

Now when I execute the program and choose the option 'something' for the first time it calls my_function and creates the object Deployer in variable dep. When the function returns, the object should be deleted. When I type for the second time, the option 'something', python calls my_function again while it should initialise another object Deployer.
(i.e when calling again my_function it does not create another object but it uses the same as before) Memory location is the same for both, so they are the same object.

Is it a normal behaviour? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Memory location is the same for both

Unless you are attaching a C-level debugger, I doubt you have this information.

> so they are the same object.

Because CPython and PyPy are well written, you would expect them to reuse memory in this way. In fact, I suspect you're seeing recycling of the ids.

Edit: Note also that recycling ids in this way is completely safe. At no time are there two objects live with the same id. The only way this can go wrong is if a program stores ids. There is no reason to do that.

Comment: @Atem18 Try to introduce some change into the 1st object but not the 2nd to see for sure if they're really the same.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev This would be impossible; the test never retains the object across function calls. That's why this recycling of ids occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Marcin is right. The objects are re-using the same memory location as they go out/in scope.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime

def main():
    while True:
        input()
        my_function()

def my_function():
    dep = Deployer()
    print(hex(id(dep)))
    dep.do_something()

class Deployer:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            print(self.time)
        except AttributeError as ex:
            print(ex)

        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
'Deployer' object has no attribute 'time'
0x7f2072d79f60
2015-01-16 05:47:51.561046

'Deployer' object has no attribute 'time'
0x7f2072d79f60
2015-01-16 05:47:51.926064

'Deployer' object has no attribute 'time'
0x7f2072d79f60
2015-01-16 05:47:52.241109

'Deployer' object has no attribute 'time'
0x7f2072d79f60
2015-01-16 05:47:52.547327

'Deployer' object has no attribute 'time'
0x7f2072d79f60
2015-01-16 05:47:52.892630
```